# Prevent shortcuts pinned to the taskbar by a script from being removed when re-running the script

Tags: powershell, shortcut, taskbar

I have a script that pins application shortcuts to the Windows Taskbar.

The script I have works fine when pinning the shortcuts. However, if the script is run for a second time it will then remove the shortcuts it previously pinned.

The issue appears to be here:

```
$appWord = "C:\Temp\Word.lnk"
$appWord = "C:\Temp\Excel.lnk"
$apps = @($appWord, $appExcel)

foreach($_ in $apps)
{
($shortcuts.ParseName($_).verbs() | ? {$_.Name -match "Tas&kbar"}).Doit()
}
```

How can I stop the pinned items being removed if they already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude verbs that have the word "unpin" in them:

```
$apps | % {
  $verb = $shortcuts.ParseName($_).verbs() | ? {
    $_.Name -match "Tas&kbar" -and $_.Name -notmatch 'unpin'
  }
  $verb.Doit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the links are present here:

```
C:\Users\Your-User-Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

before try to pin.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `$item.Verbs() | ? {$_.Name -eq 'Pin to Tas&kbar'}`